# File structure for custom modules in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, installation, drupal-modules, directory-structure

**Note:** I have already posted this question on [SE's drupal] but didnt got any positive response there so i am posting same question here again.

---

I want to organize `non-core`(modules that are not bundled with core) modules in Drupal 7. This is my proposed structure:

1. Contributed modules - downloaded modules that are untouched
2. Custom modules - downloaded modules that are modified to suit the requirement
3. local modules - self-developed modules

I GUESS, the best approach for this is to make three folders within `sites/all/modules` like below:

1. `sites/all/modules/contrib`
2. `sites/all/modules/custom`
3. `sites/all/modules/local`

Now, there are two ways to install a module:

1. Manually
2. From the admin panel

While installing the new module manually, everything is fine. I can just go to the directory and place the module there. But **how to install a newly downloaded module in `` `sites/all/modules/contrib `` from admin-panel. Moreover, is there any better approach for organizing non-core modules?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after banging head on google for hours, asking question on SO and SE's drupal and communicating with other users via comments, I cracked it...

Well, the directory structure is still debatable but satisfactory for me. But the answer to the most imp question is **"DRUSH"**.

Refer [this](https://drupal.org/node/371298) and [this](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/drush) node from Drupal. Collectively, it has everything needed to answer my entire question.

I would also like to point you to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94944/file-structure-for-custom-modules-in-drupal-7#answer-94956) answer which has provided the first and most-imp hint to me.